# Import id to refer from one object to another

Tags: data-loader, import-id

I have 3 objects A, B and C. C is junction object between A and B. A and B contain import id. Now I want to connect both A and B on C using import Id from Data Loader. My requirement is I just want to add the import ids of both A and B object to excel sheet and want to insert record to C object. Is it possible? How can I achieve it? Or I need to go for trigger. Please guide me.

Comment: you can use data loader. Map them with id field and then insert the record.

Comment: importId, Is it different from record Id ?

Comment: Also, did these records come from a different system/org?

Answer (score -1):

It is possible and you don't need any trigger. If C is junction object, it should have lookup for both A and B objects (lets say lookup field ids are accountId and contactID). In excel, make sure to populate each row with accountId and contactId for the C object.